# Querying a loging table with dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am new with c# and also with dapper. I wrote a simple console application that simulates the login process. I am trying to query a login table using dapper with parameters. I am not getting through even though the user and password are correct. I would appreciate any directions to accomplish a successful login testing.

[image]

```
    public class Login
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public Login()
        {
        }
        public Login(string username, string password)
        {
            UserName = username;
            Password = password;
        }
    }
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static string Con(string name)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public class DataAccess
    {
        public List<Login> GetLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.Con("Stock")))
            {
                var output = connection.Query<Login>("sp_GetLogin @UserName, @Password", new { UserName = username, Password = password }, commandType:CommandType.Text).ToList();
                return output;
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string txtusername;
        string txtpassword;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Username:");
        txtusername = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Password:");
        txtpassword = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Username typed: {0}, Password typed: {1}", txtusername, txtpassword);

        Login login = new Login();


        DataAccess obj = new DataAccess();

        obj.GetLogin(txtusername, txtpassword);

        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (login.Password == txtpassword)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User credentials successfull");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Password don't match");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Username don't match");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the return value of the DataAccess.GetLogin.

```
var login = obj.GetLogin(txtusername, txtpassword).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then do the credential check.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Login login = new Login();

    DataAccess obj = new DataAccess();

    obj.GetLogin(txtusername, txtpassword);
```

oh lawd.

```
    DataAccess obj = new DataAccess();

    Login login = obj.GetLogin(txtusername, txtpassword);
```

You really need to learn how to debug, stepping through each line of your code, examining what's going on and why it isn't what you expected. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging

Comment: I did debug it. I got it run